# How to launch Chrome or Chromium using an existing user profile in Playwright

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, automation, chromium, playwright

I'm using playwright and TS. 
I'm currently executing my test with the default playwright setup (it's incognito if I remember correctly)
and I want to execute some tests with my own chrome profile.

I tried to search for `user-XXX` or `profile` properties in chromium `LaunchOptions` object,
but no luck. 
of course I've checked the docs and nothing. 
I've asked some AI tools and no help either.

Something like this:

```js
const browser = await chromium.launch({
      channel: "chrome",

      // Here is what I'm looking for
      user_data_dir: "C:\\Users\\Home\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
      // or
      user: ""
      // or
      profile: ""
    });
```

Or via BrowserContext... anything would help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `userDataDir` parameter of [`launchPersistentContext`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch-persistent-context):

```
const userDataDir = "C:\\Users\\Home\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data";
const browser = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(
  userDataDir,
  {channel: "chrome"}
);
```

Here's a complete, minimal example.

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body><script>

const result = localStorage.getItem("foo");

if (result) {
  document.body.innerHTML = `<h1>${result}</h1>`;
}
else { // user's first visit, no local storage was found
  localStorage.setItem("foo", "it worked");
  document.body.innerHTML = `<h1>visit again...</h1>`;
}

</script></body></html>
```

pw.js:

```js
const {chromium} = require("playwright"); // ^1.38.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  const userDataDir = "test";
  browser = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(userDataDir);
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8000");
  console.log(await page.locator("h1").textContent());
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Output:

```bash
$ python -m http.server &  # serve the page at http://localhost:8000
$ node pw  # first run, no session exists yet
visit again...
$ node pw  # second run, session is preserved
it worked
$ rm -rf test  # destroy the session
$ node pw
visit again...
```